# Is it a proper way to send empty request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**My Example works**, but I want to now if it is a good way to send empty request like my example below.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#home").click(function (e) {

    // Prevent default form action
    e.preventDefault();

    // AJAX Request
    $.ajax(
      {
        url: "/command/home",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
          alert(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
          alert("Error!" + error);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Thank You!

Comment: why would you send empty data? (also better for code reviews SE)

Comment: This is opinion based and will probably be closed, but there is nothing wrong with sending an empty request if you don't need anything else. If for example, you are tracking all the times the home button is clicked.

Comment: What is an "empty request"? This isnt empty, you're issuing a GET request to a URI.

Comment: Probably better for codereview.se ([check their help first](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/)), but the only issue I see is that you're not handling errors or success, and you're relying on trailing commas in object initializers not being an error (which is a relatively recent thing).

Comment: I would add a try catch in my server and display a window error in case of an error

Comment: you way is correct but one correction use e.preventDefault(); before ajax request.

Comment: Aaron Harun, Exactly I'm tracking when button is clicked, no need for sending some data

Comment: @Kano then you can use localStorage - you don't need to make an ajax request just for that

Comment: Thank you all, I will add try/catch and will move e.preventDefault(); before ajax request

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Code Review won't accept this, since it's example code without context.

Comment: @Mast - I said: *"...([check their help first](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/))..."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just helping out with the "probably" part.

Comment: @Mast - And the point of pointing them at the help was so they would know to provide context and just generally play by CR's rules.